# Jboss caching angular fiìles

Tags: angular, tomcat, jboss

I have an angular 13 application deployed in a war file under jboss and tomcat application server.

The users complains that every deploy of changes, they have to force a refresh of cached files with ctrl+f5 in browser to see the latest updates.

I build the angular application with --output-hashing=all flag, but still not working.

I'm not an expert of application servers, so I need some help.

Is there something to configure on the application server to force the download of the updated js/css dependencies of the angular web app?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You could do a version check at the start of your application lifecycle, so that the version on the server correspond to the one in the client.
If the client does a mismatch with the current version being different from the one on the server, force a window reload like this:

```
window.location.reload(true)
```

Comment: seems like a workaround... but I don't know if a reload force the download of the files.... there must be a cleaner way.... I hope

Comment: The problem is that the angular application runs on a browser that you can't control like you would on a native desktop app. I hope too they will implement a better way to do so..

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is on the application server that creates a response header with cache-control max age with a big number. I m looking for a way to intercept the request and change this value

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help you more but I found [this](https://www.digitalsanctuary.com/java/jboss/setting-cache-headers-from-jboss.html). Maybe could be useful for you